# Magento, translate phrases of the wishlist and cart alert

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, mini-cart, wishlist

I'm trying to translate the phrases that appear in the alert when trying to delete the item from the wishlist or in the shopping cart.

I refer to these two sentences:
- Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the your Wish List?
- Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?

I tried to translate these sentences into my translate.csv but it doesn't work.

Where can I find these alerts?

Thanks for any help